# Convert HTML Table to JSON (Python)

Tags: python, html, json, beautifulsoup

I have many HTML tables and I'm trying to convert it to json format but my code only works for the first horizontal table (First Image) and not the second vertical table(second Image) ...

I have attached my code and sample tables here

[image: HTML Table 1]

The Code I've tried so far

```
html_data=Path("Table2.html").read_text()
table_data = [[cell.text for cell in row("td")]
                         for row in BeautifulSoup(html_data,features="lxml")("tr")]
json_data=[]
for list1 in table_data:
    list1 = [i.replace('\n', '') for i in list1]
    dict1 = dict(itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(list1)] * 2, fillvalue=""))
    json_data.append(dict1)
print(json_data)
```

The Output for the above HTML Table:

```
[{'Address': '41 B Market street'}, {'City': 'Gujarat'}, {'Postal/Zip Code': '123456'}, {'Product Details': ''}, {'Pallet Dimension': '10" x 10" x 10"'}, {'Total Weight': '1375 LBS'}]
```

[image: HTML Table 2]

```
[{'Pickup Location': 'Description', '': ''}, {'Some Address': 'Rubics cube', '': ''}, {}, {'PLTS': 'total weight', 'L': 'W', 'H': ''}, {'1': '20', '40': ''}, {'2': '60', '40': ''}]
```

The HTML code for Table 2

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td colspan="2" style="width:130.9pt; border-top:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid black 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:15.0pt" width="175">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><b><span style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; color:black">Pickup Location</span></b></p>
</td>
<td colspan="3" style="width:130.1pt; border-top:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid black 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:15.0pt" width="173">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><b><span style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; color:black">Description</span></b></p>
</td>
<td style="width:1.5pt; padding:0in 0in 0in 0in; height:15.0pt" width="2">
<p class="MsoNormal"></p>
</td>
<td style="width:.3pt; padding:0in 0in 0in 0in; height:15.0pt" width="0"></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:13.15pt">
<td colspan="2" rowspan="2" style="width:130.9pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:13.15pt" width="175">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><b><span style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; color:black">Some Address</span></b></p>
</td>
<td colspan="3" rowspan="2" style="width:130.1pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt; border-right:solid black 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:13.15pt" width="173">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><b><span style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; color:black">Rubics cube</span></b></p>
</td><td style="width:1.5pt; padding:0in 0in 0in 0in; height:13.15pt" width="2">
<p class="MsoNormal"></p>
</td>
<td style="width:.3pt; padding:0in 0in 0in 0in; height:13.15pt" width="0"></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.75pt">
</tr>
<tr style="height:.3in">
<td style="width:42.15pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; background:#D9E1F2; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:.3in" width="56" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><b><span style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; color:black">PLTS</span></b><b><span style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif"></span></b></p>
</td>
<td style="width:88.75pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; background:#D9E1F2; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:.3in" width="118" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><b><span style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; color:black">total weight</span></b><b><span style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif"></span></b></p>
</td>
<td style="width:20.15pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; background:#D9E1F2; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:.3in" width="27" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><b><span style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; color:black">L</span></b><b><span style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif"></span></b></p>
</td>
<td style="width:20.15pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; background:#D9E1F2; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:.3in" width="27" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><b><span style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; color:black">W</span></b><b><span style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif"></span></b></p>
</td>
<td style="width:17.0pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; background:#D9E1F2; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:.3in" width="23" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><b><span style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; color:black">H</span></b><b><span style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif"></span></b></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:13.9pt">
<td style="width:42.15pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:13.9pt" width="56" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><span style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; color:black">1</span></p>
</td>
<td style="width:88.75pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:13.9pt" width="118" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><span style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">20</span></p>
</td>
<td style="width:20.15pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:13.9pt" width="27" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><span style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">40</span></p>
</td>
<td style="width:20.15pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:13.9pt" width="27" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><span style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">40</span></p>
</td>
<td style="width:17.0pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:13.9pt" width="23" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><span style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">40</span></p>
</td>
<td style="width:.3pt; padding:0in 0in 0in 0in; height:13.9pt" width="0"></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:13.15pt">
<td style="width:42.15pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:13.15pt" width="56" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><span style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; color:black">2</span></p>
</td>
<td style="width:88.75pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:13.15pt" width="118" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><span style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">60</span></p>
</td>
<td style="width:20.15pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:13.15pt" width="27" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><span style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">40</span></p>
</td>
<td style="width:20.15pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:13.15pt" width="27" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><span style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">40</span></p>
</td>
<td style="width:17.0pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:13.15pt" width="23" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><span style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">40</span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The desired output for the second table:

if the table is an Horizontal table(Table 1) then the old output is enough

```
[{'Address': '41 B Market street'}, {'City': 'Gujarat'}, {'Postal/Zip Code': '123456'}, {'Product Details': ''}, {'Pallet Dimension': '10" x 10" x 10"'}, {'Total Weight': '1375 LBS'}]
```

if the table is an vertical table (Table 2) then the output should look like:

```
[{'Pickup address': 'some address'}, {'Description': 'Rubicks cube'}, {'PLTS': ['1','2']}, {'Total weight': ['20','60']}, {'L':['40','40']}, {'W':['40','40']},{'H':['40','40']}]
```

I've tried changing the code but doesn't work for me
Any suggestions ???

Comment: How do you want the output to be structured for the second table? Can you include that in your question?

Comment: @HenryEcker Added that in the question

Comment: `{'PLTS': '1','2'}` is not a valid `dict` in python. Do you want a string `'1,2'` or do you want a `list` `['1', '2']`?

Comment: @HenryEcker List should be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to make this solution as generic as possible while also fulfilling the specific case presented. This will only work for the second case, as without `th` elements or specific classes only on header elements, it cannot be determined whether the headers are vertical or horizontal programmatically.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pathlib import Path
import itertools

html_data = Path("table.html").read_text()
table_data = [[td.text.strip() for td in tr("td") if td.text.strip()]
              for tr in BeautifulSoup(html_data, features="lxml")("tr")]

out = [{t: rest if len(rest) > 1 else rest[0]} for k, g in
       itertools.groupby(table_data, key=bool) if k for t, *rest in zip(*g)]
print(out)
```

output:

```py
[{'Pickup Location': 'Some Address'}, {'Description': 'Rubics cube'}, {'PLTS': ['1', '2']}, {'total weight': ['20', '60']}, {'L': ['40', '40']}, {'W': ['40', '40']}, {'H': ['40', '40']}]
```

table.html

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr style="height:15.0pt">
        <td colspan="2"
            style="width:130.9pt; border-top:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid black 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:15.0pt"
            width="175">
            <p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><b><span
                    style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; color:black">Pickup Location</span></b>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3"
            style="width:130.1pt; border-top:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid black 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:15.0pt"
            width="173">
            <p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><b><span
                    style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; color:black">Description</span></b>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:1.5pt; padding:0in 0in 0in 0in; height:15.0pt" width="2">
            <p class="MsoNormal"></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:.3pt; padding:0in 0in 0in 0in; height:15.0pt" width="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:13.15pt">
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"
            style="width:130.9pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:13.15pt"
            width="175">
            <p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><b><span
                    style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; color:black">Some Address</span></b>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3" rowspan="2"
            style="width:130.1pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt; border-right:solid black 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:13.15pt"
            width="173">
            <p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><b><span
                    style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; color:black">Rubics cube</span></b>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:1.5pt; padding:0in 0in 0in 0in; height:13.15pt" width="2">
            <p class="MsoNormal"></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:.3pt; padding:0in 0in 0in 0in; height:13.15pt" width="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:15.75pt">
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:.3in">
        <td style="width:42.15pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; background:#D9E1F2; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:.3in"
            width="56" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
            <p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><b><span
                    style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; color:black">PLTS</span></b><b><span
                    style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif"></span></b></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:88.75pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; background:#D9E1F2; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:.3in"
            width="118" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
            <p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><b><span
                    style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; color:black">total weight</span></b><b><span
                    style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif"></span></b></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:20.15pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; background:#D9E1F2; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:.3in"
            width="27" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
            <p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><b><span
                    style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; color:black">L</span></b><b><span
                    style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif"></span></b></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:20.15pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; background:#D9E1F2; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:.3in"
            width="27" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
            <p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><b><span
                    style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; color:black">W</span></b><b><span
                    style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif"></span></b></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:17.0pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; background:#D9E1F2; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:.3in"
            width="23" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
            <p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><b><span
                    style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; color:black">H</span></b><b><span
                    style="font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif"></span></b></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:13.9pt">
        <td style="width:42.15pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:13.9pt"
            width="56" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
            <p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><span
                    style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; color:black">1</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:88.75pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:13.9pt"
            width="118" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
            <p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><span
                    style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">20</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:20.15pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:13.9pt"
            width="27" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
            <p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><span
                    style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">40</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:20.15pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:13.9pt"
            width="27" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
            <p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><span
                    style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">40</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:17.0pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:13.9pt"
            width="23" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
            <p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><span
                    style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">40</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:.3pt; padding:0in 0in 0in 0in; height:13.9pt" width="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:13.15pt">
        <td style="width:42.15pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:13.15pt"
            width="56" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
            <p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><span
                    style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; color:black">2</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:88.75pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:13.15pt"
            width="118" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
            <p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><span
                    style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">60</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:20.15pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:13.15pt"
            width="27" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
            <p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><span
                    style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">40</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:20.15pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:13.15pt"
            width="27" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
            <p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><span
                    style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">40</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:17.0pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; height:13.15pt"
            width="23" valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap">
            <p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:center" align="center"><span
                    style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">40</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```